# How does a C-Store know to which C-Get it belongs? DICOM

Tags: dicom

My question is: how does a C-Store-Rq, which is caused by a C-Get-Rq, know to which C-Get-Rq it belongs?

For the C-Move Service it is obvious, because there is a 'Move Originator Message ID' and a 'Move Originator Application Entity Title' field in each C-Store-Rq.

So what happens if two or more C-Get-Rq are sent to one archive at the same time (or quickly one after the other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C-GET request does not cause a new association to be generated. The instances are returned on the same association as the C-GET.

A C-MOVE request will cause a C-STORE to be generated on a separate association.

So, if you have two, simultaneous C-GET associations open, it is clear which association requested which (a separate association need not be generated).

Comment: According to http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part07.html#sect_9.1.3.2 there are C-Store suboperations generated for each match, or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: My mistake. It does generate C-STORE messages, but they are on the same Association, so there is no question as to which request they came from. I'll edit my answer to correct the terminology.

Comment: But can one SCU send a second C-Get-Rq,over the same Association while the first C-Get operation is still running on that Association? Or can the next operation only be invoked when the current one has finished ? For that reason it's interesting if a C-Store knows to which C-Get it belongs

Comment: Ok the answer is for the synchronous mode obvious, because an operation can only start if the one before has finished. And for the asynchronous mode it's mostly irrelevant, because most serivces (e.g. Storage Service) doesn't support the asynchronous mode.